# Android compass calibration without moving

Tags: android, gps, compass

I want to calibrate the compass of an android tablet, I know I can do it by doing the "8' figure, but, I want to do a calibration without moving it because my tablet is fixed and can't be moved. Is there any method to simply add or remove some degrees to the compass offset?.. in other words, if my compass shows that my heading is 260 degrees and I know is 300, can I add 40 degrees to adjust it?

I havey device rooted but on the last android versions the filesystem is not writable, is readonly. With Magisk I can write some script to update many files.. Or maybe there is a simple app to do that.

Thanks

Comment: hi, sorry to hear you're having issues, but stackoverflow tries to answer programming related issues and tries to stay away from these recommendation type questions as there isn't an unambiguously correct answer.  that said, you might have luck with using an external compass that feeds its data to the tablet via a debug interface.  I'd expect this would require writing some code to get everything talking compatible protocols, but it's possible there are off-the-self solutions available